# Is there a keyboard shortcut for Don't Save?

Tags: macos, keyboard

One thing I do a lot is <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> over to TextEdit, jot down some notes, and then decide to throw them away.  I can close the window with <kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd>, but is there a way to not-save it from just the keyboard?

Escape simply cancels the close. <kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> takes the file-picker to the Desktop (and I thought this used to work, pre-Lion, but maybe I'm just imagining it).

Is there a keyboard shortcut for Don't Save, short of turning on Full Keyboard Access?

Comment: It did exist pre-Lion; you aren't imagining it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The default shortcut was changed to ⌘⌫ on Lion.

You can change it back to ⌘D with `defaults write -g NSSavePanelStandardDesktopShortcutOnly -bool true`. It won't affect some applications like TextEdit though.

Comment: Great!  Can I ask how you knew this?

Comment: It's been mentioned here and on other websites multiple times.

Comment: It's listed in [Apple's big list of keyboard shortcuts (aka KB #HT1343)](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1343).

Comment: _"Command-Delete: Select Delete or Don't Save in a dialog that contains a Delete or Don't Save button"_ (from the previous link). I just tested ⌘⌫ on OS X Yosemite with Atom and it works too, so it may be generalized to other OS X versions and apps too!